# 'Type set is not JSON serializable' but data is dict - python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, set

I am using Microsoft's graph API to send an email, and  so that I can dynamically adjust the contents of the email I am setting the payload of the email to use a msg variable that will be adjusted based on some input. I am setting this as a dict for the sake of readability like this:

```
payload = {
    "message": {
        "subject": "Some Subject",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "Text",
            "content": msg
        },
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                "somememail@email.com"
                }
            }
        ]    
    },
    "saveToSentItemn": "false"  
}
```

And then I was going to use json.dumps(payload) to convert it to the necessary format for the API. However, json.dumps throws an error:

```
TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable
```

I don't see how this is a set. I should not sending the email via the API works fine when everything is setup like this:

```
payload = "{\n    \"message\": {\n        \"subject\": \"Some Subject\",\n        \"body\": {\n            \"contentType\": \"Text\",\n            \"content\": \"Some content.\"\n        },\n        \"toRecipients\": [\n            {\n                \"emailAddress\": {\n                    \"address\": \"someemail@email.com\"\n                }\n            }\n        ]\n    },\n    \"saveToSentItems\": \"false\"\n}"
```

But it is terrible to read. Anyone see my mistake in the payload causing the error?
Thanks

Comment: fixed... can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, curly brackets can be used to initialize a set ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#set-displays)).

In your payload, the value for `emailAddress` is wrapped in `{}`:

```
{
    "emailAddress": {
    "somememail@email.com"
    }
}
```

Note:

```
>>> x = {"somememail@email.com"}
>>> type(x)
<class 'set'>
```

Adding a key inside the curly brackets will turn your set into a dictionary:

```
{
    "emailAddress": { 
        "address": "somememail@email.com"
    }
}
```